# How do you pass a parameter to mysql query in a rails rake task?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am changing the encoding of all my tables from `latin1` to `utf8mb4` using a rails rake task.

I want to:

1. Grab all the tables where the encoding is NOT utf8mb4
2. Change the character set for each of those tables.

I can grab all the tables that have the wrong enconding with

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-STRING
   SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE collation <> 'utf8mb4'
STRING
```

I'm stuck with how to pass the `table name` for each of those tables to the mysql query so that the table encoding can be altered.

```
results.each do |table|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-STRING
  ALTER TABLE #{table.table_name} CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
  STRING
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Each result is an array:

```
results.first.class
 => Array
```

And the first value returned by `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is the table name.  So you should be able to use something like:

```
results.each do |table|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-STRING
  ALTER TABLE #{table[0]} CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
  STRING
end
```